# mesh is white in texture mode

Tags: texturing, uv-image-editor

i dont understand why only the hands and the eyes are colorable, the rest of the mesh is white and i cant seem to be able to apply textures to it

this picture shows my uv islands on the left and the mesh in edit mode on the right

[image]

this picture shows the same uv screen left and my mesh in texture paint mode on the right

[image]

Comment: Please post your images with the Blender SE tools so that they show up directly in your question.

Comment: To understand how to add images to your question please read: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post